# MySQL multiple table select query group

Tags: mysql

I got 2 tables

table oc_1234567890

```
| time                |  S363  |  S342  |  
| 2015-04-20 22:39:17 | 19.12  | 19.43  |   
| 2015-04-20 22:36:49 | 19.12  | 19.43  |  
| 2015-04-20 22:34:20 | 19.12  | 19.43  |  
| 2015-04-20 22:31:52 | 19.12  | 19.43  |   
| 2015-04-20 22:29:23 | 19.18  | 19.43  |
```

table oc_1122334455

```
| time                |  S352  |   
| 2015-04-20 22:38:03 | 15.68  |   
| 2015-04-20 22:35:34 | 15.68  |   
| 2015-04-20 22:33:06 | 15.68  |   
| 2015-04-20 22:30:38 | 15.68  |   
| 2015-04-20 22:28:09 | 15.68  |
```

And need to merge it group by time round to 1, 2 or 5 min
and take 200 records from 1440
expect an array like this:

```
$array = [                
     "2015-04-20 22:38" => {
    "S352" => "15.68",  "S363" => "19.12",  "S342" => "19.43",     }            
     "2015-04-20 22:35" => {
    "S352" => "15.68",  "S363" => "19.12",  "S342" => "19.43",     }            
     "2015-04-20 22:33" => {
    "S352" => "15.68",  "S363" => "19.12",  "S342" => "19.43",     }            
     "2015-04-20 22:30" => {
    "S352" => "15.68",  "S363" => "19.12",  "S342" => "19.43",     }            
     "2015-04-20 22:28" => {
    "S352" => "15.68",  "S363" => "19.18",  "S342" => "19.43",     }  
];
```

Please help with suggestions!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just process the returned data in php? Doing a lot of logic in a query will *probably* a). be hard to maintain b). be slow

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

SELECT LEFT(time, 16) minute, S352, S342, S363 FROM oc_1234567890 a JOIN oc_1122334455 b ON LEFT(a.time, 16) = LEFT(b.time, 16)

This would be real slow with large datasets. I might make an intermediate mapping table that maps `time` to whatever 1, 2, or 5min internals you want.